# Can I only traverse a DatabaseConnection object once?

Tags: 7, database

I have a database query result, and I want to go through the records twice. However, the second time I go through it, nothing happens. It seems you can only iterate through this object once?

My code looks like this:

```
$query = db_select( ... );
$result = $query->execute();
if ( $result->rowCount() > 0 ) {
  foreach ( $result as $record ) {
    ... processing happens here
  }
}

// now loop through again, to mark records as processed, upon success.
foreach ( $result as $record ) {
  ... additional processing here
}
```

And the additional processing doesn't happen.

As a work around, I added `$records = $result->fetchAllKeyed();` before the initial processing, and then the result object had no records!

I found nothing in [the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/interface/DatabaseStatementInterface/7) about resetting the object or anything.

Is this how the object works? Can I reset the iterator again, or must I fetch the keys initially to have an array that I can iterate over many times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour; Drupal wraps around PDO and this is how PDO query functions behave also. Have a look at [Is it possible to rewind a PDO result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278259/is-it-possible-to-rewind-a-pdo-result) for a more in-depth discussion.

The standard way to get around this would be to use either `fetchAllKeyed()` as you've mentioned, or `fetchAll()` instead. The latter will produce an array of object results that can be iterated over as many times as you want.

```
$query = db_select( ... );
$result = $query->execute();
if ( $result->rowCount() > 0 ) {
  $data = $result->fetchAll();

  foreach ($data as $item) {
    // do something with data
  }

  foreach ($data as $item) {
    // do something with data again
  }
}
```